# How to get a specific value from a string name via config

Tags: java, bukkit

The green is the lore
and the yellow is the displayname
http://puu.sh/k2iI7/62619f9536.jpg

I'm trying to seperate them in there rightful places for some odd reason there both appearing in both of the places.

items.java

```
public ItemStack applyLore(ItemStack stack, String name, String lore1){
    ItemMeta meta = stack.getItemMeta();
    meta.setDisplayName(name.replaceAll("&([0-9a-f])", "\u00A7$1"));
    ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();
    lore.add(lore1.replaceAll("&([0-9a-f])", "\u00A7$1"));
    meta.setLore(lore);
    stack.setItemMeta(meta);
    return stack;
}

// p.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Integer.parseInt(s), 1));

public void giveItemfromConfig(Player p)
{
    String name ="name:";
    String lore ="lore:";
    for ( String s : plugin.file.getFile().getStringList(plugin.file.path) ) {
        try {

            s.split(" ");
            if ( s.contains(name) || s.contains(lore) )
            {
                String namelength = s.substring(name.length());
                String lorelength = s.substring(lore.length());

                p.getInventory().addItem(applyLore(new ItemStack(Integer.parseInt(s.split(" ")[0])),
                        namelength.replace("_", " ").replace("ame:", "").replace("e:", "").replace("lor", "").replace("ore", ""),
                        lorelength.replace("_", " ").replace("lor:", "").replace("e:", "").replace("am", "").replace("lor", "").replace("ore", "")));
                p.sendMessage("debug");


            } else {
                ///nope.exe
                p.getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Integer.parseInt(s)));

            }

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Error in Config, Your id must be a integer ERROR:" + e);
        }
    }

}
```

config.yml

```
    ChestPopulater:
  items:
  - 276 name:cookie
```

Comment: Try replacing `s` with `s.split(" ")[0]"` when parsing it as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is the problem is because of "Integer.parseInt(s)".
I dont know why you added this one as we dont have full source code or idea what you are trying to do with String "s" so that you will get result.
If you are doing it to get "276" , I will suggest you to do following :

String s2 = s.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]","").replace(":","").trim();
Integer i = Integer.parseInt(s2);

Comment: I updated my code with the fix for my last problem right now i'm trying to seperate the displayname and lore as of right now. http://puu.sh/k2iI7/62619f9536.jpg The yellow is the displayname and the green is the lore and for some odd reason there both in appearing in the displayname and lore @chetanpawar